# Can't Import TFLite Model To Android Studio, How To Solve It?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tensorflow, tflite

I have a problem where I can't import a new Tflite model to android studio. the Tensorflow Model TFLite feature seems to be disabled. The message says "Requires Android Gradle plugin 4.1.0-alpha04 or newer). How can I import the TFLite model into the android studio?

My problem can be seen in the following image
[image]

Comment: Hi Annisa! Please upgrade the Android plugin once as It is popping up in right bottom corner to see whether the issues are getting resolved or not.

Comment: Path to load the TFLite model - New -> Other -> Tensor flow Lite Model . Please make sure you are using latest android studio version . Ref [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66497749/11530462), [2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45373#issuecomment-973723865) .